# How to install typo3 extension in composer via xampp shell command

Tags: xampp, composer-php

I want to install the typo3 extension via composer so i have edited my composer.json file. 
Like. "typo3-ter/fluidpages": "^4.0.0"
and saved it. 
Now in xampp shell command i did like 
d:\server\test

## composer update

afterwards it took some time but came up with some errors. i don't know that what should i do in command line in order to get it done. I am beginner in it,
any help would be greatful
Thanks

Comment: what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Dont edit your composer.json file, just run

```
composer require typo3-ter/fluidpages
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require
This will update your composer.json automatically and install the package.

Since v4 is currently latest release of typo3-ter/fluidpages you dont need to specify the version like

```
composer require typo3-ter/fluidpages:4
```

Comment: It worked in this way as well, and i also just wrote the 'composer update' and it installed the extensions. and i also installed the **Ecodev/typo3-cms-speciality-distribution**. But now i am trying to activate it from backend in extension manager but its giving me an error, which is ** 
Extension Manager is in offline mode. No TER connection available.** now i don't have any idea why it is creating this problem, rest of all extension are working fine like i can activate and deactivate them without having any issue. if you have idea please tell me. Thanks

Comment: the question sounded like it was a composer problem, but  its a typo3 problem. you better ask your question in typo3 context. i cant help you there.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249763/extension-manager-is-in-offline-mode-no-ter-connection-available-in-typo3)     here i have asked please have a look?