# Extension Manager is in offline mode. No TER connection available in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I have installed TYPO3 Version 7.6.15 by using composer and also I am using the Xampp version 7.0.0. I have installed many extensions and activated them successfully at the backend of my TYPO3 page. 
Now, I have installed the **Ecodev/typo3-cms-speciality-distribution** via composer. and i am trying to activate it from extension manager but it is giving me following error. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us27B.jpg)

Now, I have no idea, what to do? at this link https://github.com/Ecodev/typo3-cms-speciality-distribution
it is written to **deactivate EXT:fluid_styled_content, EXT:context_help, EXT:func**, so i did, but still the same error. Any help will be grateful thanks.

Comment: In Composer Mode functionality of the Extension Manager is limited.

Comment: So, how can i activate it? is there any way?. Thanks

Comment: @ivoba here i have asked?

Comment: https://wiki.typo3.org/Composer#Extension_Manager

Comment: i read it, the same my composer is working fine, because i installed it. and as the wiki describes that we can only activate it and that the point where am i getting the error?.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i found the error, it is just because when we installed the speciality distribution package, we also need to install and activate all the other dependencies which are important for this package. 
After installing them, this problem will resolved. As, i was using it via composer mode. 
Thanks